# Python pycurl List separation

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, split, pycurl

I'm playing with Python and I would like to know how do I make the script automatically identify the parameters and values of parameters when they are given?

```
import os
import pycurl, re, cStringIO
from urllib import urlencode
import Queue
import threading
import sys
import socket
import io

def curl(host,option,params):

try:

    if option == "GET":

        buf = cStringIO.StringIO()

        c = pycurl.Curl()

        c.setopt(c.URL, host)   
        c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
        c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
        c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
        c.setopt(c.USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36')
        c.setopt(pycurl.NOSIGNAL, 1)
        c.perform()
        html = buf.getvalue()

        print html

    elif option == "POST":

        buf = cStringIO.StringIO()

        c = pycurl.Curl()

        c.setopt(c.URL, host)

        x = params.split(":")[0]
        y = params.split(":")[1]
        post_data = {x:y}
        postfields = urlencode(post_data)
        c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, postfields)          
        c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
        c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
        c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
        c.setopt(c.USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36')
        c.setopt(pycurl.NOSIGNAL, 1)
        c.perform()
        html = buf.getvalue()

        print html

except pycurl.error,e:

        print e

curl('localhost/b.php','POST','par1:val1|par2:val2|par3:val3')
```

So far I can do it manually but is boring editing the code everytime and addings these split functions for each parameters.

How do I make this the code to automatically post the parameters and the values, like this?:

```
[par1] => val1
[par2] => val2
[par3] => val3
```

My actual results:

python p.py
Array
(
    [par1] => val1|par2
)

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems you need to extract a worker fucntion like below to 
reuse your code for calling `curl`:

```
def run_curl(host):
    """Run curl on provided parameters"""
    buf = cStringIO.StringIO() 
    c.setopt(c.URL, host)   
    c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
    c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
    c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
    c.setopt(c.USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36')
    c.setopt(pycurl.NOSIGNAL, 1)
    try:
       c.perform()
    except pycurl.error:
       raise
    return buf
```

`if option == "GET":` you cannot really get rid of inyour setup, but you can make the part of code inside it much smaller by extracting a worker function.

Also for this tasks [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) seem a good choice.

Comment: Hi there, I wanted to make a curl function and when I call the OPTION is gonna be POST or GET, do not look at GET, look at POST, the parameters I write are not working correctly, what I want is the script to automatically detect all parameters and values of those parameters when POST is called.

Comment: So why not take away GET part from your question as it not related to the actual problem? for the parameter part is kwargs you are looking for?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3

Comment: Because it's the full code, so people can understand what I've done. Basically POST must find out what parameters and their values I used into the curl() call function and use them with the         c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, postfields)          function

Comment: From [posting guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): *Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence: what details can you include that will help someone identify and solve your problem?*... GET code is not helpful in identifiing the parameters issue. Anyways, does kwarg link solve it?